# laravel auth vue tailwindcss and fontawesome error

Tags: laravel, npm

please some help.
npm run dev gives me an error

```
ERROR in ./resources/sass/fontawesome_app.scss (./node_modules/css-loader??ref--5-2!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss0!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--5-4!./node_modules/sass-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--5-5!./resources/sass/fontawesome_app.scss)
Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/src/index.js):
Error: Failed to find '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css'
  in [
    /var/www/html/resources/sass
  ]
    at /var/www/html/node_modules/postcss-import/lib/resolve-id.js:35:13
 @ ./resources/sass/fontawesome_app.scss 2:14-265
```

I have a new laravel installation with auth and vue. First I installed tailwind;

```
composer require laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss --dev
artisan ui tailwindcss --auth
npm install
npm run dev
```

Tailwind removed some stuff from the laravel project, so now i try to make fontawesome work again. (i had it working before installing tailwindcss)

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

in webpack.mix.js i add

```
.sass('resources/sass/fontawesome_app.scss', 'public/css')
```

I created the file resources/sass/fontawesome_app.scss;

```
// Fonts
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/all.css';
```

In the head of my welcome.blade.php;

```
<!-- Styles -->
<link href="{{ mix('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="{{ mix('css/fontawesome_app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

i compiled all code by running;

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

And now i got that error. I named the css like that so it doesn't conflict with
the webpack lines tailwind created.

Please some help!

Answer (score 0):

I changed resources/sass/fontawesome_app.scss into this and it gave me no errors anymore;

```
// Fonts
$fa-font-path: "../webfonts";
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands.scss';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular.scss';
```